# conda is not not able to create env, not activating env and also jupyter is not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

I am getting this error I am just playing with Linux commands and I noticed a change suddenly that my conda is not responding so I cannot able to activate my env, make new env, or open Jupiter notebook. I have many projects in my system so how to mitigate this error
before this error when everything is right I always have a (base) name in front of my terminal like the below one
(base)rahul@linux:~$ conda

but now I am getting this only with errors
rahul@linux:~$ conda
Could not find platform independent libraries 
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to [:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding

Current thread 0x00007fad7aed0740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)

if I uninstall and reinstall conda what happen to my env then I am in fear

Comment: You ran only `conda`, nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but on a plain Debian 10, without conda (and without action on my part).

Python3.5 was working well but python3.7 (linked to python3) was crashing with the same error. I tried every PYTHONPATH I could  think of, but nothing worked, and I don't think it could do anything because `python3 -vvv` shows that the encoding package is well found and imported.

Then I thought it was my locales. (some pretty interesting infos here https://vstinner.github.io/python37-new-utf8-mode.html but didn't found my answer)

At the end all I could do to fix it, was to reinstall python3.7 from source (with apt it didn't work), and then reinstall all needed packages. (if you're missing lsb_release check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965043/no-module-named-lsb-release-after-install-python-3-6-3-from-source) : it's in `/usr/share/pyshared`)